# Web parsing using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to parse data from a website: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/community.

I am trying to scrape the time of the post. For example "21 hours ago".

HTML code of the site. I am trying to extract time from
**<span class = "F....>21 hours ago<...**

```
<li class="comment Pend(2px) Mt(5px) Mb(11px) P(12px) " data-reactid="24">
 <div class="Pos(r) Pstart(52px) " data-reactid="25">
  <div class="Fz(12px) Mend(20px) Mb(5px)" data-reactid="26">
   <div class="avatar D(ib) Bdrs(46.5%) Pos(a) Start(0) Cur(p)" data-reactid="27">...</div>
   <button aria-label="See reaction history for Chef" class="D(ib) Fw(b) P(0) Bd(0) M(0) Mend(10px) 
    Fz(16px) Ta(start) C($c-fuji-blue-1-a)" data-reactid="31">Chef</button>
     
     <span class="Fz(12px) C(#828c93)"><span>21 hours ago</span></span>
   
   <div class="Wow(bw)" data-reactid="33">...</div>
   <div class="Py(4px)" data-reactid="39">...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   <div class="Pos(r) Pt(5px)" data-reactid="45">...</div>
 </div>
</li>
```

The issue is, I am not able to find the  time after reading the data using beautifulsoup. Here is the code which I have written.

```
source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

content = soup.find('ul' , class_= "comments-list List(n) Ovs(touch) Pos(r) Mt(10px) Mstart(-12px) Pt(5px)")

li = content.find('li' , class_ = "comment Pend(2px) Mt(5px) Mb(11px) P(12px)")
print(li.prettify())
```

**Output**

```
li = content.find('li' , class_ = "comment Pend(2px) Mt(5px) Mb(11px) P(12px)")
print(li.prettify())
<li class="comment Pend(2px) Mt(5px) Mb(11px) P(12px)" data-reactid="24">
 <div class="Pos(r) Pstart(52px)" data-reactid="25">
  <div class="Fz(12px) Mend(20px) Mb(5px)" data-reactid="26">
   <div class="avatar D(ib) Bdrs(46.5%) Pos(a) Start(0) Cur(p)" data-reactid="27">
    <div class="Pos(r)" data-reactid="28">
     <div class="avatar-text Ta(c) Bdrs(48%)" data-reactid="29" style="background-color:#ff333a;color:#fff;font-size:24px;line-height:40px;width:40px;height:40px;" title="See reaction history for Chef">
      �
     </div>
     <img alt="Chef" class="avatar-img Bdrs(48%) Pos(a) StretchedBox Bgc(#400090.03)" data-reactid="30" height="40" src="https://s.yimg.com/it/api/res/1.2/H4mqpmacU.CnalUl7leuZA--~A/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7dz04MDtoPTgwO3E9ODA-/https://s.yimg.com/gq/1735/40147141066_fc6972_o.jpg" title="See reaction history for Chef" width="40"/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <button aria-label="See reaction history for Chef" class="D(ib) Fw(b) P(0) Bd(0) M(0) Mend(10px) Fz(16px) Ta(start) C($c-fuji-blue-1-a)" data-reactid="31">
    Chef
   </button>
   <!-- react-empty: 32 -->
  </div>
  <div class="Wow(bw)" data-reactid="33">
   <div class="C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px) Pend(8px)" data-reactid="34">
    <!-- react-text: 35 -->
    I managed to pick up an Xbox series X and I have to say the tech is very impressive (bought it not knowing).  This only makes up around 10% of Microsoft’s business and slated to out perform PS5.  I personally believe this stock is still undervalued.  Longs stay strong!
    <!-- /react-text -->
   </div>
   <div class="Pos(r) D(ib) Lh(12px)" data-reactid="36">
    <video autoplay="" class="W(a) Mah(320px) My(3px) H(a) Maw(100%)" data-reactid="37" height="236" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" poster="https://media.tenor.com/images/e239c83d92cd0e896dc8b9ac05be0bf4/tenor.png" width="258">
     <source data-reactid="38" src="https://media.tenor.com/videos/1eff610b01f69f793fe1f267c88bbbd4/mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Py(4px)" data-reactid="39">
   <div class="D(ib) Pos(r)" data-reactid="40">
    <div class="Fz(12px) Px(8px) Mend(4px) Va(m) Bdrs(3px) C($c-fuji-grey-g) Bgc($c-fuji-grey-b) Cur(d) Py(3px)" data-reactid="41">
     <div class="D(ib) Mend(6px) Cur(d) Cur(p)" data-icon="traffic" data-reactid="42" style="vertical-align:middle;fill:#333;stroke:#333;stroke-width:0;width:18px;height:18px;">
     </div>
     <!-- react-text: 43 -->
     Bullish
     <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- react-empty: 44 -->
  <div class="Pos(r) Pt(5px)" data-reactid="45">
   <div class="D(ib)" data-reactid="46">
    <button class="reply-button O(n):h O(n):a P(0) Bd(n) Cur(p) Fz(12px) Fw(n) C(#828c93) D(ib) Mend(20px)" data-reactid="47">
     <svg class="Mend(6px) Cur(p)" data-icon="reply" data-reactid="48" height="15" style="fill:#828c93;stroke:#828c93;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;" viewbox="0 0 25 20" width="15">
      <path d="M12.8 5.8V2.4c0-.4-.2-.7-.6-.8-.3-.2-.8-.1-1.1.1L.9 8.8c-.2.2-.4.4-.4.7s.2.6.4.8l10.2 7.1c.3.2.7.3 1.1.1.3-.2.6-.5.6-.8v-3.3h1.3c3 0 6.1.6 8.5 5.2.2.3.5.5.9.5h.3c.5-.1.8-.6.7-1C23 7.3 18.5 5.9 12.8 5.8zm-.1 5.6h-1c-.6 0-1 .4-1 .9v2.4L3.2 9.5l7.5-5.2v2.4c0 .5.5.9 1 .9 4.2 0 7.9 0 9.8 6.3-2.9-2.6-6.3-2.6-8.8-2.5z" data-reactid="49">
      </path>
     </svg>
     <!-- react-text: 50 -->
     Reply
     <!-- /react-text -->
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="D(ib) Pos(r)" data-reactid="51">
    <button aria-label="8 Thumbs Up" class="O(n):h O(n):a Bgc(t) Bdc(t) M(0) P(0) Bd(n) Mend(20px)" data-reactid="52">
     <svg class="Cur(p)" data-icon="thumbsup-outline" data-reactid="53" height="12" style="vertical-align:middle;fill:#828c93;stroke:#828c93;stroke-width:0;" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="12">
      <path d="M2.4 21.7V11.6h2.1c1.1 0 1.7-.7 2.1-1.1.7-.7 1.5-1.4 2.2-2.1.3-.2.5-.4.7-.6 1.6-1.8 2.3-3.4 2.2-5.5 0 0 .1-.1.3 0 .5.1 1 .6 1.1 1.6.3 2.4-.2 4.3-.7 4.7-.9.7-.4 2 .8 2h7.1c.7 0 1.3.4 1.3.8 0 .3-.5.8-.7.8-1.6 0-1.6 2.1-.1 2.2 0 .1.1.2.1.4 0 .1 0 .2-.3.3-.3-.1-.5-.1-.7-.1-1.3 0-1.7 1.7-.5 2.2 0 0 .2.1.3.2.2.2.3.3.3.6 0 .1-.1.1-.3.3-.2.1-.5.2-.7.2-1.3.2-1.4 1.9-.1 2.2l.1.1s.2.2.2.5c0 .4-.2.6-.6.6l-16.2-.2zM20.3 8.3h-5.1c.4-1.3.6-2.9.3-4.7-.2-2-1.5-3.3-3.1-3.6-1.7-.3-3.2.7-3.1 2.4.1 1.5-.4 2.6-1.7 4l-.5.5c-.6.7-1.3 1.4-2 2-.3.2-.5.4-.7.5H1.2c-.7 0-1.2.5-1.2 1.1v12.3c0 .7.6 1.2 1.2 1.2h17.3c1.6 0 3-1 3-2.8 0-.5-.1-.9-.3-1.2.7-.5 1.1-1.1 1.1-2 0-.5-.1-.9-.3-1.3.7-.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-2 0-.4-.1-.9-.3-1.3.6-.5 1-1.3 1-2.1.1-1.8-1.7-3-3.6-3z" data-reactid="54">
      </path>
     </svg>
     <span class="D(ib) Va(m) Fz(12px) Mstart(6px) C(#828c93)" data-reactid="55">
      8
     </span>
    </button>
    <button aria-label="0 Thumbs Down" class="O(n):h O(n):a Bgc(t) Bdc(t) M(0) P(0) Bd(n)" data-reactid="56">
     <svg class="Cur(p)" data-icon="thumbsdown-outline" data-reactid="57" height="12" style="vertical-align:middle;fill:#828c93;stroke:#828c93;stroke-width:0;" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="12">
      <path d="M21.6 2.3v10.1h-2.1c-1.1 0-1.7.7-2.1 1.1-.7.7-1.5 1.4-2.2 2.1-.2.2-.4.4-.5.6-1.6 1.8-2.3 3.4-2.2 5.5 0 0-.1.1-.3 0-.5-.1-1-.6-1.1-1.6-.3-2.4.2-4.3.7-4.7.9-.7.4-2-.8-2H3.9c-.7 0-1.3-.4-1.3-.8-.2-.2.4-.6.5-.6 1.6 0 1.6-2.1.1-2.2 0-.1-.1-.2-.1-.4 0-.1 0-.2.3-.3s.5-.1.7-.1c1.3 0 1.7-1.7.5-2.2 0 0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.2-.2-.3-.3-.3-.6 0 0 .1-.1.3-.2.3-.1.6-.2.7-.2 1.3-.2 1.4-1.9.1-2.2L5 3.3s-.1-.2-.1-.5c0-.4.2-.6.6-.6l16.1.1zM0 12.7c0 1.8 1.8 3 3.7 3h5.1c-.4 1.3-.6 2.9-.3 4.7.3 1.9 1.5 3.3 3.1 3.5 1.7.3 3.2-.7 3.1-2.4-.1-1.5.4-2.6 1.7-4 .2-.2.3-.4.5-.5.7-.7 1.4-1.3 2.1-1.9.3-.2.5-.4.6-.5h3.2c.7 0 1.2-.5 1.2-1.1V1.2c0-.7-.6-1.2-1.2-1.2H5.5c-1.6 0-3 1-3 2.8 0 .5.1.9.3 1.2-.8.5-1.2 1.2-1.2 2 0 .5.1.9.3 1.3-.7.4-1.2 1.1-1.2 2 0 .4.1.9.3 1.3-.6.6-1 1.3-1 2.1" data-reactid="58">
      </path>
     </svg>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

If I print this line of code the output says "None".

```
date =  content.find('span' , class_="Fz(12px) C(#828c93)")
print(date)
```

**Output**

```
None
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening or help with the code which reads the time of the post (**21 hours ago**)?

Thank you .

Comment: could you please provide the exact URL of the post?

Comment: post ? If you mean the URL of the yahoo finance page I am parsing, Here it is. https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/community?p=MSFT @schezfaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `output` as "None" because BeautifulSoup gets the HTML Source from the initial Request and it doesn't have the Posted time values. Those values are rendered after the initial request. To capture those kinds of values you can use a library like "Selenium". When you use selenium, you can wait till the page loads and then pass that HTML Source into BeautifulSoup and try out. Below is a sample code created to get a basic understanding:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/community')
html = driver.page_source


try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'comment Pend(2px) Mt(5px) Mb(11px) P(12px)')))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # Rest of the code
except TimeoutException:
    print("Load failed")
```

Comment: Yes, it was just a small example to help you to get an idea. Please consider approving the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response  =  requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/community")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```